# tcpdf generates square at the and of string

Tags: javascript, php, css, svg, tcpdf

I have an issue with `TCPDF`. I am getting `square` at the end of string.
Actually what i am doing is generating `PDF` using `svg` image.

Here is the code,

```
$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->AddPage('L', $page_format, false, false);
$pdf->ImageSVG($uploadPath, $x=16, $y=16, $w=$width+$margin, $h=$height+$margin, $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=false);     
$pdf->output($filename, 'D');
```

Its working great for some `svg`(i have many svg with different fonts, so we can say some fonts not generating square).
Here is the image

[image]

After some research i modified `svg` image content
From,

```
<g transform="translate(1189.73 792.69)">
  <text font-family="Arvo" font-size="25" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
     <tspan x="-100" y="7.87" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)">Type Text Here</tspan>
  </text>
</g>
```

To,

```
<g transform="translate(1189.73 792.69)">
  <text font-family="Arvo" font-size="25" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;"><tspan x="-100" y="7.87" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)">Type Text Here</tspan></text>
</g>
```

And it worked for me. Any idea what happening there? Not sure its `svg` issue or `tcpdf`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the SVG, so it is definitely TCPDF.  The rectangle you are seeing is what some fonts display when you try to print an undefined character.

Since it went away when you removed whitespace, I guess TCPDF is trying to print a carriage return character (13) or something.

You may wish to report the bug to the TCPDF folks.